# Unable to connect to default SQL instance using a custom TCP port without specifying port in connection string

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, database-administration

- Server A has a default SQL instance running on TCP port 12345.
- Server A has the SQL browser service running.
- Server B (on the same subnet) can connect to Server A using SSMS with/without specifying the port number.
- If Named Pipes protocol is disabled on Server A, Server B can no longer connect without specifying the port number.
- If an Alias is created on Server A, Server B still can't connect without specifying the port number.

Is there a way to have Named Pipes disabled and connect to Server A without specifying the port number?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - TCP/IP is definitely enabled on Server A. Server B is only running SSMS.

Comment: 1.Shared Memory , 2.TCP/IP, 3.Named Pipes

Comment: Just to clarify, Named Pipes is disabled for MSSQLSERVER., not for the client protocols.

Comment: If you're wanting Server B to connect to Server A then the alias for Server A needs to be created on Server B. Your question currently suggests that the alias for Server A was created on Server A itself. When creating the Server A alias make sure it's created in both the 32-bit and 64-bit Alias collections.

Comment: That was it! I had to create an alias on Server B. Thank you.